# Postfix LL for type long long

Tags: c++

This is about something very basic.

While defining type long long the expression is like.

```
long long x=5435666LL;
```

I cant understand why LL is post fixed  since even without post-fix its quite clear for the compiler to allocate the right memory space(8 bytes in vc++) which it anyways does in absence of post-fix.

So what purpose does 'LL' post-fix serves?

Answer (score 5):

Your code is equivalent to

```
long long x;
x = 5435666LL
```

Without the `LL` suffix, `5435666` is an `int`. In either case the result is the same because `5435666` fits in an `int`, unless you're on a 16 bit platform.

Comment: so please help me on this. Even with or without LL compiler is assigning 8 bytes(memory space for long long type) and not 4 bytes(memory space for int type) so again whats the point of using suffix?

Comment: Perhaps habit or consistency so that one also does it for the times when it does matter.

Comment: @user1619447: it can matter when you call a function that's overloaded. E.g., if there is `void foo(long)` and `void foo(int)`, then `foo(1L)` picks the `long` overload and `foo(1)` picks the `int` overload. Using the `L` prefix you can force the `long` overload without having to know if your number fits in an `int` or not.

Answer (score 3):

Without a suffix, the compiler will choose the first of `int`, `long int` and `long long int` in which the value will fit. However, you might specifically want a value that would fit in an `int` to be of `long long int` type. For that you would use the `LL` suffix.

Contrived example:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T x) {
  static_assert(std::is_same<T, long long>::value, "Must be long long!");
}

int main()
{
    foo(0); // Error because 0 without a suffix is an int
    foo(0LL);
}
```

To demonstrate that these literals have different sizes (assuming `int` and `long long int` have different sizes in your implementation), consider [the following example](http://ideone.com/ERpQpF):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(0) << ' ' << sizeof(0LL) << std::endl;
}
```

For me, this outputs:

```
4 8
```

Comment: so please help me on this. Even with or without LL compiler is assigning 8 bytes(memory space for long long type) and not 4 bytes(memory space for int type) so again whats the point of using suffix?

Comment: @user1619447 No, without the suffix it's an `int` if it fits in an `int` and will use however many bytes an `int` takes up. With the suffix, it will always take up the number of bytes required for a `long long`.

Comment: one time I did this                                                 long long x= 5435666LL;                                             cout << sizeof(x) << endl;                                           and second time                                                  long long x= 5435666LL;                                             cout << sizeof(x) << endl;                                        both giving the result as 8, dosen't it mean it assigning long long irrespective?

Comment: @user1619447 You've defined `x` as a `long long`. `x` itself will of course have the size of a `long long`. It's the *integer literal* that will be of a different size.

Answer (score 1):

In your example it has only a cosmetic purpose.

I can think of the following examle where it could make a difference, because the literal is assumed to be `int`:

```
enum {
    Flag1 = 1 << 0,
    Flag2 = 1 << 33,
    Flag3 = 1LL << 33;
}
```